# Use navbar-toggle to social media buttons on header

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm doing a web and trying to put the social media buttons at header. If I use the class navbar-toggle, when it toggle, the smaller buttons appear well, but the bigger ones (that i use when the screen is not toggled) don't disapear. I can delete this "bigger" buttons when is toggled ?? (Im new on this and i'm lost)
Thanks !

this is the code when is toggled:

```
< a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">

< img src="/Content/socialNetworkImages/logoFacebook256.png" width="40" height="40" style="position:absolute;left: 70px; top: 0px " class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" />
< /a>


< a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank">

< img src="/Content/socialNetworkImages/logoTwitter256.png" width="40" height="40" style="position:absolute;left: 120px; top: 0px" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" />
< /a>
```

The non toggled is the same without the class (i didn't found a class opposite to toggled)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here but I can tell you that

```
data-target=".navbar-collapse"
```

in the img tag is not pointing to any class. Therefore it will not collapse any element. Ensure that you point to a defined target.